# Resetting a value every month - swift & firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two integer values called `Score` and `Highscore`. I am using firebase to store values, users and such. I was wondering, if it was possible to reset a users `Score` every month? Like when we reach the 1st of the month, every users `Score` is set to 0?

Is that even possible? I sure hope so!

PS. Sorry for not showing any code, but I believe it is irrelevent at this point - let me know if you think otherwise :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should better add an App Engine backend which has a simple servlet and a cron task. This backend is going to update your Firebase database monthly.

Backend:

- Servlet; updates all scores to 0 except the top score.
- Cron task; calls the servlet monthly.

See this link; [Adding backend logic using App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio):