# I am using Firebase RealTime DB.. I want to do is to make all of users' scores zero

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase RealTime Database. For example, i have 100,000 users, all of which have different scores. What i want to do is to make all of users' scores zero at one time. How can i do that?
By the way, the content of the "score" field is "integer."

Comment: You're asking about a multi-location update, and I address that in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462074/using-updatechildvalues-to-delete-from-firebase/38466959#38466959). However, if there's a need to write the same value to 100,000 child nodes, there may be more of a Firebase structure issue than anything and you may need to alter the structure to better handle that. Without understanding the use case or structure, it's impossible to answer accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is possible. A better way is to create a separate tag for scores.

```
Users
 - User1
   - data
 - User2
   - data
 - User3
   - data
```

```
Scores
 - User1: 56
 - User2: 30
 - User3: 23
```

This way you can simply delete the `Score` tag and reset all users.

Another way would be traversing through the whole database and resetting the value with firebase cloud functions.

Another way would be using [App Engine backend which has a simple servlet and a cron task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488204/resetting-a-value-every-month-swift-firebase)

Comment: You can definitely write to multiple locations at one time. 100,000 is probably not practical but it can certainly be done. See my comment to the question. Oh - and this is a very good answer with great suggestions - just wish the question was a bit more clear.

Comment: Users have user_id,user_name,email and score.. And for example I have 100.000 users.. 
ahmet - 5200 points
mehmet - 6500 points
ali - 7200 points
........................
.......................
.......................
I want to do all users score "0(zero)"..
How Can I Do??

Comment: @EgemenAY That comment is your question re-posted as a comment. If you have more information to add, please update your question with that information.